# Go back to URL in user's history

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a couple of forms that are on 6 different pages (step by step). Users chosen information is saved and echoed at the top of the page in "sessions", but I want the user to be able to edit any information that was set... I have tried using `history.back()` however it's not an option for me. So I decided to have a try with linking history URL. What I mean is something like this:

```
echo "<td id='1'><a href='javascript:history.back(' url here  ')' id='stext' style='text-decoration:none';>" . $str  ."</a></td>";
```

It was unsuccessful...

Please give me some suggestions:)
Thanks:)

Comment: Why use history.back, not a normal link to the perticular step. Then load the data in the form to recreate the page as it was when the user left the page?

Comment: OK, but how do you load the data to recreate the form? @DavidLaberge

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean history.go(-1); But then again i would make regular urls to the corresponding steps:

`<a href="?step=1">back to step 1</a> 2 <a href="?step=3">forward to step 3</a>`

(that last one shoud be a submit button in your situation? or for that matter the first one should be a button too, so the current answers in your page will be saved when you go back to the previous page)